# WordPress Loop Takes Custom Meta from other Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I used Devin Says' Team Post Type as a base for a custom post type with custom meta: https://github.com/devinsays/team-post-type. My plugin is virtually unchanged, aside from language updates and added fields.

When I output my posts, Custom Meta values that are empty for subsequent posts in the loop take the value of previous posts. So - if the Custom Meta of 'telephone' for Post One is set to '555-555-5555' and the Custom Meta of 'telephone' for Post Two is not set, in my loop, it displays '555-555-555'.

So - the HTML output (for example) would look like:

```
<section>
    <h2>Person 1</h2>
    <p>555.555.5555</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Person 2</h2>
    <p>555.555.5555</p>
</section>
```

... even when there is no phone number in the database for Person 2.

I found this similar question which has the same symptom, but did not see a 'solution' that would help me - the recommendations that are stated are things I am doing already, and I do not see a critical difference in the way that I am calling data to the page: [Values from custom meta boxes being repeated in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779259/values-from-custom-meta-boxes-being-repeated-in-posts)

Does anyone have a suggestion regarding this problem?

I'm trying to output my posts using the following:

```
add_shortcode('staff-list', 'jpro_staff_list'); 
function jpro_staff_list($atts) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
), $atts)); 

$args = array ( 
    'post_type' => array( 'staff' ), 
    'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order'   => 'ASC' 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$staff_list = '<div class="jpro-staff staff-list container">';  

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {                                   
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); 

        $post   = get_post($id);
        $postID = $post->ID;

        $image  = get_the_post_thumbnail( $postID, 'medium', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' ));
        $name   = get_the_title($postID);   
        $bio    = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
        $title  = get_post_meta($postID, 'staff_title', true);
        $video  = get_post_meta($postID, 'staff_video', true);
        $email  = get_post_meta($postID, 'staff_email', true);
        $phone  = get_post_meta($postID, 'staff_phone', true);
        $fax    = get_post_meta($postID, 'staff_fax', true);        

        if(!empty($image)){ 
        $output_image = '<div class="staff-list image">'.$image.'</div>';
        }

        if(!empty($name)){
        $output_name ='<h3 class="staff-name staff-list">'.$name.'</h3>';
        }

        if(!empty($bio)){
        $output_bio ='<div class="staff-bio staff-list">'.$bio.'</div>';
        }

        if(!empty($video)){
        $output_video ='
            <div class="staff-video-container">
                <iframe class="staff-video staff-list" src="//www.'.$video.'" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
                </iframe>
            </div>';
            }

        if(!empty($title)){
        $output_title ='<li class="staff-title staff-list">'.$title.'</li>';
        }

        if(!empty($email)){
        $output_email ='
            <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">
                <li class="staff-email staff-list"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> '.$email.'</li>
            </a>';
            }

        if(!empty($phone)){
        $output_phone ='
            <a href="tel:'.$phone.'">
                <li class="staff-phone staff-list"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> '.$phone.'</li>
            </a>';
            }

        if(!empty($fax)){
        $output_fax ='<li class="staff-fax staff-list"><i class="fa fa-fax"></i> '.$fax.'</li>';
        }               

            $staff_list .='<section class="jpro-staff staff-list">';
            $staff_list .= $output_name;
            $staff_list .= $output_video;
            $staff_list .= '<ul class="staff-meta staff-list">';
            $staff_list .= $output_image;
            $staff_list .= $output_name;
            $staff_list .= $output_title;
            $staff_list .= $output_email;
            $staff_list .= $output_phone;       
            $staff_list .= $output_fax;
            $staff_list .= '</ul>';
            $staff_list .= $output_bio;             
            $staff_list .= '</section>';
    }
} else {
    $staff_list .='<p>Ooops! No Staff Found.</p>';
}

$staff_list .='</div>';     
wp_reset_postdata();
return $staff_list; 

}
```

Comment: Your shortcode is poorly written and has a ton of bugs.

Comment: Also, `$id` is undefined, yet another bug added to the many others ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically your script works correctly. Because you **never clear the `$output_xyz` variables at any time** your script assumes the value from the last loop.

Either change your `if ( !empty (...) ) ...` to have an `else` block like this:

```
if ( !empty ( $phone ) ) {
    $output_phone = '<a href="tel:'.$phone.'">...</a>';
} else {
    $output_phone = '';
}
```

Or clear the variables at the beginning of each loop:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {                                   
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $output_image = '';
        $output_phone = '';
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: *Technically your script works correctly*, No, it does not. It is really buggy and **still** uses `extract()` on top of that

Comment: @PieterGoosen Might be. But that was not his question and I didn't pay attention to that. Regarding to his question, the script does exactly what he told him to do. Or in other words: He should tell the script what it should not do, like in that specific case use old values from a previous loop. :P

Comment: Perfect, Mario. That does solve my problem.

@PieterGoosen, I see there is documentation at WP Codex that doesn't include extract() - when/if I use attributes for this shortcode, I will use the new technique. Do you have other thoughts that I might benefit from regarding buggyness?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be great if you accept the answer as solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: @JamesRyvenValeii apart from the points in this answer and `$id`, you should be good to go. Always turn debug on, you should have got many debug errors on page if debug was turned on. `extract()` is a really really bad function that was completely removed from all WorPress functions. You should have a most evil list with `query_posts()`, `extract()` and `eval()` right at the top. Never ever use any of those